# Extend Page Access Token for Facebook as an Analyst role

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the extended page access token as a Analyst role of the page (not admin/moderator/editor) etc.

I am so far only able to get the page access token, but unable to extend it.

I do not have the APP ID/APP Secret hence I am unable to follow the steps in which many of the guides have mentioned :(

Are there any other ways for me to get the permanent/long-lived page access token?

Answer (score 0):

You can ONLY get a Page Token if you manage the Page. And you can ONLY get any Token with an App. Here are the steps to get an Extended Page Token:

- Get a User Token with Facebook Login
- Extend the User Token
- Get an Extended Page Token for a specific Page with this endpoint: `/{page-id}?fields=access_token`

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: so as an Analyst role I cant extend the Page Access Token? But I managed to get a Page Access Token as a Analyst role. From FB, under the Analyst role, it states "Analysts can see which admin created a post or comment and view insights.
"

To add on, I used the Graph API instead of a specific app. hmmm im quite confused!!

Comment: if you got a page token for the page, you can extend it too. read through the links in my answer, how to extend tokens is explained very well in there. even by only using the api explorer.